# Windows 10 Iot HDMI CEC

Tags: hdmi, windows-iot

Has anyone figured out how to either compile libcec for windows on an ARM device, or found another solution to enable HDMI-CEC commands to be used with Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: CEC in which direction? From the Pi to a TV?

Answer (score 2):

As of recently, no. Reference link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=111021

Also, `libcec`'s author is working on it, but there's no ETA. Here's the [Github issue](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/issues/130). Check the last few messages.

You could push your luck by exposing the CEC wires in an HDMI cable then bit-banging it with your GPIO port. Pin 13 if I'm not mistaken, [red wire wrapped in foil together with white](http://g03.s.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1o68kFVXXXXb1XpXXq6xXFXXXp/206184536/HTB1o68kFVXXXXb1XpXXq6xXFXXXp.jpg).That suggestion might be a little too extreme.

<sup>You could do it for science.</sup>

Comment: This isn't really considered _recent_. It was created last year and was last commented on about 3 months ago.

Comment: @dylan The word "recent" is relative. It may differ with different people. We're different, apparently :)